# AWS SES Dedicated IP Pool Limit for Multi-Tenancy App

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, multi-tenant, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

In my multi-tenancy laravel web project I want to implement an email module so my tenants can send email to their customers. And of course I want to isolate the ip reputation from one tenant to another.

After researching for a while, dedicated ip (managed) seemed like a good fit to achieve this, but I found out that there is a limit of 50 dedicated ip pool in total for an AWS account. But what if I have more then 50 tenants and I want to manage them in one account. What should I do?